# Connect to external Kafka brokers via istio egress gateway

Tags: apache-kafka, routes, openshift, istio

My app deployed in openshift cluster needs to connect to 2 external kafka brokers. Since the application is on the istio mesh, all outbound traffic must go through the egress gateway. The connection to kafka is via the log4j2 appender over SSL.
I made the following istio config:

```
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: se-kafka
spec:
  hosts:
    - kafka1.host.com
    - kafka2.host.com
  addresses:
    - 10.200.200.1
    - 10.200.200.2
  ports:
    - name: kafka-port
      number: 9093
      protocol: TCP
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  resolution: NONE
  exportTo:
    - .
=====================
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: dr-kafka
spec:
  host: egressgateway #name egressgateway deployment
  subnets:
    - name: se-kafka
=====================
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gw-kafka
spec:
  servers:
    - hosts:
        - kafka1.host.com
      port:
        name: kafka1-egress-port
        number: 16001
        protocol: TCP
    - hosts:
        - kafka2.host.com
      port:
        name: kafka2-egress-port
        number: 16002
        protocol: TCP
 selector:
   istio: egressgateway
=======================
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: vs-kafka
spec:
  hosts:
    - kafka1.host.com
    - kafka2.host.com
  gateways:
    - mesh
    - gw-kafka
  tls:
    - match:
        - gateways:
            - mesh
          port: 9093
          sniHosts:
            - kafka1.host.com
      route:
        - destination:
            host: egressgateway
            port:
              number: 16001
    - match:
        - gateways:
            - mesh
          port: 9093
          sniHosts:
            - kafka2.host.com
      route:
        - destination:
            host: egressgateway
            port:
              number: 16002
    - match:
        - gateways:
            - gw-kafka
          port: 16001
          sniHosts:
          - kafka1.host.com
      route:
        - destination:
            host: kafka1.host.com
            port:
              number: 9093
    - match:
        - gateways:
            - gw-kafka
          port: 16002
          sniHosts:
          - kafka2.host.com
      route:
        - destination:
            host: kafka2.host.com
            port:
              number: 9093
========================
```

It works. But I think that traffic bypasses the istio egressgateway. There is no connection in kiali between ServiceEntry and Egressgateway. And if you look at the egressgateway logs, you can see the following warning:

```
gRPC config for envoy.api.v2.ClusterLoadAssigment rejected: malformed IP address: kafka1.host.com. Consider setting resolver_name or setting cluster type to 'STRICT_DNS' or 'LOGICAL_DNS'
```

What is the problem and how to properly configure the egress gateway?

Comment: Perhaps resolution should be set to DNS in service entry? See https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway/#egress-gateway-for-http-traffic

Comment: What is your istio version? Based on the warning it looks the Ingress is not able to resolve this DNS name. You might need to add a [DestinationRule](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#ClientTLSSettings-TLSmode) which says don’t use TLS when talking to `kafka1.host.com` and `kafka1.host.com` as that Pods doesn’t have sidecars in it.

Comment: @Jakub How can I check istio version? `kafka1.host.com` and `kafka2.host.com` is not Pods, it is brokers worked outside openshift. Are you suggest setting the following value trafficPolicy.tls.mode = DISABLE ? But in reality, the connection uses the SSL protocol, will this not affect?

Comment: You can check istio version with `istioctl version`. Could you first try to change your service entry resolution from `resolution: NONE ` to `resolution: DNS` as Joel mentioned? With DNS resolution, the gateway performs a DNS query to get an IP address of the external service and directs the traffic to that IP address. If that won't work you can check this [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/16806) which suggest to make 2 gateways if you have multiple hosts. If that won't work I would check if it's gonna work with destination rule with any tls mode, just for test if it helps.

Comment: @Jakub I cant install istioctl and i only have oc. So i tried all of this and nothing has changed. I post new question more on the theoretical part to help me understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64206521/how-the-request-is-routed-when-using-egress-gateway