# How the request is routed when using egress gateway

Tags: apache-kafka, routes, openshift, istio

Imagine the following situation: application A work inside service mesh and application B is external service for appA. App A should send a tcp request to app B.

In the simple case, we set up one `ServiceEntry` with `hosts` and `resolution: DNS` and it works fine.

But how is the request routed when I connect the egress gateway? The tutorial on the Istio website says to apply the ServiceEntry, DestinationRule, Gateway, VirtualService configurations. My opinion is that the request path will be as follows:

```
appA -> Mesh Gateway -> VirtualService -> Egress Gateway -> VirtualService -> ServiceEntry -> appB
```

Where is the DestinationRule used along the way and why?

In my case, the role of application B is performed by a bunch of kafka brokers. So I need to configure a tcp connection with SSL to all brokers. I have all the hosts of brokers, what is the correct way to configure the connection to them? I tried using one ServiceEntry for all hosts but the error is `"multiple hosts provided with non-HTTP,non-TLS ports"`.

Does this mean that I need to 1) create one ServiceEntry for each host, or 2) specify the IP addresses of the hosts directly?

Comment: I can't give a comprehensive answer, however I'm using strimzi to deploy kafka in kube, what I can see is that several brokers are created as part of a StatefulSet, and are accessed through a standard kube Service. So, from the app, brokers are accessed via the service URL (I'm not sure exactly who's in charge of the load-balancing, if it's part of the strimzi machinery or not) ; but this unique URL then can be used in service entry to address several brokers

Comment: About your question on DestinationRule, it can serve several purposes but if you're talking about this example: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway/#egress-gateway-for-http-traffic all it does is defining a subset that is further used in VirtualService. So in your schema it would goes with it: `... -> VirtualService+DestinationRule -> ...` ; I wouldn't try to represent it as a autonomous entity, actually, all of that happens in app's sidecar in/out

Comment: Also, not sure what you refer to as `Mesh Gateway` but it probably doesn't fit there.

Comment: @Joel **About kafka:** unfortunately there is no way to change the location of kafka brokers. **About mesh gateway:** it was my mistake, I only recently found out that `mesh` is the reserved name for all sidecars

Comment: Hi @pwflamy, About the issue with multiple hosts there is comment about that in code on [github](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/pkg/config/validation/validation.go#L2330-L2336). About Destination Rule, did above answer from Joel explained everything or you still have any doubts about that?

Comment: @Jakub Hi, yeah i have a little misunderstanding. What exactly does the subset highlight in this example? My opinion is that nothing and this is just shown as an example. And about TCP traffic: when resolution type is NONE hosts are ignored, so is there any way to keep the application able to send requests over the host? Maybe something like a static DNS table? or it will be easier to specify IP addresses to the application

Comment: this is strange, but I noticed that the connection to the Oracle database works successfully when I specify `resolution: DNS`, `port TCP` and specify the host. But specifically with connecting to kafka servers, this setting does not work.